# Problems with Bleak and aioconsole Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, arduino, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi everyone I'm trying to run a code that I found in [github](https://github.com/Ladvien/arduino_ble_sense/blob/master/app.py) this if to connect with Arduino Nano BLE 33 Sense, a few months ago I didn't have any problems to run it in Windows with Visual Studio Code, but since yestarday was printing this error:

```
from aioconsole import ainput
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aioconsole'
```

Someone could help me to run this again in windows? or Raspberry Pi if is easier. Or recomendatios about codes to receive data true Bluetooth from Arduino with the BLE.h library

Comment: Has something changed with the Python virtual environment being used by VSCode? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments?

Comment: @ukBaz nothing change.